# Adicionar erro 404 url amigavel

Tags: php

Boas

Estou a fazer as rotas das urls amigáveis pelo fichiero htacess e agora queria mostrar o erro 404 caso o utilizador digite um nome que não exista.

Mas nao sei como posso fazer

Tenho o código que apresenta o conteúdo assim

```
if(!isset($_REQUEST['controller']) || empty($_REQUEST['controller'])){
       require_once("conteudos/home.php");
        }else{
            require_once("conteudos/".$_GET['controller'].".php");
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Em php com a função **curl_init();**

```
$handle = curl_init($url);
curl_setopt($handle,  CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, TRUE);

/* Obtendo o arquivo que está conectado a $url. */
$response = curl_exec($handle);

/* Checando se há erro 404 (Arquivo não existe). */
$httpCode = curl_getinfo($handle, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
if($httpCode == 404) {
    /* Aqui está a resposta do erro 404. */
}

curl_close($handle);

  /* $response aqui. */
```

Site não gerenciável Via **.htacess:** :

```
ErrorDocument 404 /404.html
```

**Joomla:**

```
if (($this->error->getCode()) == '404') {
  header('Location: /index.php?option=com_content&view=article&id=75');
exit;
}
```

**Wordpress:**

```
<?php
/**
 * The template for displaying 404 pages (Not Found)
 *
 * @package WordPress
 * @subpackage Twenty_Thirteen
 * @since Twenty Thirteen 1.0
 */

get_header(); ?>

    <div id="primary" class="content-area">
        <div id="content" class="site-content" role="main">

            <header class="page-header">
                <h1 class="page-title"><?php _e( 'Not Found', 'twentythirteen' ); ?></h1>
            </header>

            <div class="page-wrapper">
                <div class="page-content">
                    <h2><?php _e( 'This is somewhat embarrassing, isn’t it?', 'twentythirteen' ); ?></h2>
                    <p><?php _e( 'It looks like nothing was found at this location. Maybe try a search?', 'twentythirteen' ); ?></p>

                    <?php get_search_form(); ?>
                </div><!-- .page-content -->
            </div><!-- .page-wrapper -->

        </div><!-- #content -->
    </div><!-- #primary -->

<?php get_footer(); ?>
```

Comment: Não deu colooquei assim     ErrorDocument 404 /conteudos/erro.php

Comment: resolveu uma parte mas a outra acho que vou ter de verificar na base de dados se existe o item que digitou senao mostra o erro 404

Comment: O que me esta a acontecer e que agora por exemplo http://exemplo.pt/comer o comer e o nome de um artigo que bem da base de dados se eu puser http://exemplo.pt/comer/efw ele ja apresenta o erro mas se puser http://exemplo.pt/wef ela nao apresenta o erro e mostra o ficheiro vou ter de fazer verificacao na base de dados para ver se o nome existe nao e ?

Comment: Não site de raiz php mysql